# Count distinct elements in an array in O(n) only with loops and arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

I found this solution

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-distinct-elements-in-an-array/

The problem is that time complexity must be at O(n), space complexity must be at O(1), but i can't import any additional libraries and the code must be maximally short. I wasn't able to find a solution with sorting faster than O(nlog n), so i guess i need to find a clever way. And the answer is the third solution from the link above, but it requires additional library. Is it even possible to find a better way?

Edit:

In fact, i need to create a function that works exactly like 
`java.util.Arrays.stream(myarray).distinct().count();`

It must have time complexity at O(n) and space complexity at O(1).
Basically i have to create it using only ***loops***, ***arrays*** and ***if statements***. Also it is forbidden to import anything other than `import java.util.Scanner;` and because of that i can't do it with any ready to use methods like `java.util.Arrays.*;`.

For example:

Input:

`{1,12,3,0,1,3,15,6}`

Output:

`6`

Comment: Try using a `Set`

Comment: What do you mean without libraries?  One could consider the Java API a type of library as it has classes to make programming easier.

Comment: I mean the only thing i can import is java.util.Scanner, this may be the only thing that precedes the main class.

Comment: Please post a link to your stated requirements.

Comment: I have an intuition that O(1) space complexity won't be possible (with linear time), since without sorting we need some method of keeping track of what we have already seen.

Comment: Reposting a question which has been closed is taboo.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859840/function-that-counts-unique-elements-in-an-array-with-on-complexity-in-java

Answer (score 2):

*Maximally short* solution with *O(n)* time complexity, using only Java 8+ built-in APIs, i.e. *no additional libraries* needed.

The code assumes `myarray` is an array of `int`, `long`, `double`, or object<sup>1</sup>.

```
long count = java.util.Arrays.stream(myarray).distinct().count();
```

<sup>*1) Object must have valid `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementation.*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A solution in O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity is possible **in theory**, but it might not be very **practical**.  The basic idea is this:

```
let aMin be the minimum value of an entry in arr
let aMax be the maximum value of an entry in arr
let seenOnce and seenTwice be boolean arrays 
   whose indices are in the range [aMin..aMax]
initialize all elements of seenOnce and seenTwice to FALSE
countUnique = 0;
for a in arr {
    if (!seenOnce[a - aMin]) {
        // seeing `a` for the first time, so count it 
        seenOnce[a - aMin] = TRUE
        countUnique = countUnique + 1
    } else if (!seenTwice[a - aMin]) {
        // seeing `a` for a second time, so un-count it
        countUnique = countUnique - 1
        seenTwice[a - aMin] = TRUE
    }
}
```

If the values in `arr` could be any `int`s at all, then each of the `boolean` arrays will contain **2^32** entries, for a total of **over 8 billion** `boolean`s. That's **1Gb** of memory, provided  we're careful to implement all those `boolean`s in one bit each. But it *is* `O(1)`: same 1Gb consumed regardless of whether `arr` contains two elements or a billion...